# Interdependent fields in model

Tags: django, django-models

so I'm a newbie, and I searched the forums for the question but couldn't really understand 
how to apply this to my project.
So essentially, I want a field in my model that would have choices, and depending on that choice, either a boolean field or a numerical field pops up for a field of the same variable.
Any help would be tremendous, and maybe a bit of hand holding for this one, I am a very new and young programmer. 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for the first field is [Field.choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices), and after the user picks his choice you should run a function to the determine the value of the second field.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    second_field =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = True)

    def determine_second_field(self, gender_picked):
        if gender_picked == 'M':
            self.second_field = "it's a boy"
        else:
            self.second_field = "it's a girl"
```